# Magento : How to get cart info by using cartId

Tags: magento-1.9, php, cart

i want to retrieve details of items in cart created , i have a cart id , how can i retrieve the cart info(details).
i am using this code but it gives no results , please help

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["cartId"])){
  require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento umask(0); 
  $cartId=$_POST["cartId"];
  Mage::app(); 
  $quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
  $result[]=array();

  foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
    $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
    $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
    $price=0;
    $price=$product->getFinalPrice();
    $result[]=array(
      "productId"=>$item->getProduct()->getId(),
      "price"=>$price,
      "imageUrl"=>$baseImageUrl
      );
  }

    //return array of products 

  echo print_r($result);
  exit();

}else{
    echo "error";
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found an solution , what i did was that i used soap api to get product Ids and then using mage class to load other data here is the code :

```
    require_once('../app/Mage.php');//Path to Magento umask(0);
    if(isset($_GET["cartId"])){
      $cartId=$_GET["cartId"];
      echo $cartId;
      $proxy = new SoapClient('https://www.magentohost.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
      $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiuser','apipassword');
      $result = $proxy->shoppingCartInfo($sessionId, $cartId);
      $itemDetails=array();
      Mage::app(); 
      foreach ($result->items as $item) { 
        $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id);
        $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
        $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
        $price2=0;
        $price2=$product2->getFinalPrice();
        $itemDetails[]=array(
          "productId"=>$item->product_id,
          "name"=>$item->name,
          "price"=>$product2->getPrice(),
          "spprice"=>$price2,
          "imageurl"=>$baseImageUrl,
          "qty"=>$item->qty
          );
      }
        //return array of productdetails
      echo print_r($itemDetails);
      exit();
    }else{
      echo "error";
      exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have the cart id, you can do this:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId);
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) { //or $quote->getAllVisibleItems()
    //...your code here
}
```

Comment: i think he is first trying to get id from session first and then load cart

Comment: Gives an error  Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

Comment: @mahethekiller. Sorry I made a mistake. See my edit.

Comment: now i get this error
Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /home/phonatetech/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 463

Comment: did you add `Mage::app();` above the code I've written?

Comment: oh yes i commented it but still i am getting blank items array

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    // Do something more
}
```

Comment: it returns blank results nothing is returned ....,

Comment: Are you getting this in a page other than Magento ? did you checked dose it even going inside of if condition ?

Comment: page is at root of my magento website

Comment: and are you getting $cartId ? is it returning any value

Comment: yes  cart id is there

Comment: Use marius code then it will work

Comment: it Gives an error Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

do i need to include some file

Comment: $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($cartId); use this insted

Comment: now i get this error Fatal error: Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in /home/phonatetech/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 463

Answer (score 0):

**Try bellow code:**

```
         $storeId = '';
         $quoteId = 1;
         $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote");

        if (!(is_string($storeId) || is_integer($storeId))) {
            $quote->loadByIdWithoutStore($quoteId);
        } else {
            $quote = $quote->setStoreId($storeId)->load($quoteId);
        }

        $shippingaddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();

        foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
            print_r($item);
        }

        $payment = $quote->getPayment();
```

**OR**

```
$cartId = 1;
$info = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart_Api')->info($cartId);
print_r($info);
```

Comment: i got another solution thanx